# show item in list view after sax xml parsing

Tags: android

I had done xml parsing and able to display one array item in list view .but i want to display 2 array item in one list...using array adapter..means i want array_barrio and array_ciudad both in one list view how can i do this...my java class is

```
public class XMLParsingExample extends ListActivity {
    String name = null;
    private String array_estado[];
    private String[] array_ciudad;
    private String array_barrio[];
    /** Create Object For SiteList Class */
    SitesList sitesList = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);
    try {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                    "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?key=Buenos");

            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

         sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;


         array_ciudad = new String[sitesList.getEstado().size()];
         for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getEstado().size(); i++)
         {
             name = sitesList.getEstado().get(i);
             array_ciudad[i] = name;
             Log.i("array_spinner" + i, array_ciudad[i]);
         }
         array_barrio = new String[sitesList.getBarrio().size()];
         for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getBarrio().size(); i++)
         {
             name = sitesList.getBarrio().get(i);
             array_barrio[i] = name;
           //  Log.i("array_spinner" + i, array_ciudad[i]);
         }

         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_barrio));

//       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_barrio ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new String[] that is big enough to hold both, and then copy the elements of each array to the new array.  Use the new array in your ArrayAdapter.

```
String[] bigArray = new String[array_barrio.length + array_ciudad.length];
System.arraycopy(array_barrio, 0, bigArray, 0, array_barrio.length);
System.arraycopy(array_ciudad, array_barrio.length, bigArray, array_barrio.length, array_ciudad.length);
```

Another thing worth considering would be to just create the bigArray initially, and just add both sets of elements to the big array rather than the smaller ones.

Comment: @ nicholas  i used above lines and pass big array to array adapter it forse close ..      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bigArray));

Comment: 05-18 11:31:30.015: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=3 srcPos=3 dst.length=6 dstPos=3 length=3

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to combine two array items and make it as one. then you can follow nicholas way . Add both the array and make it as one array and pass the array to ArrayAdapter. But if you want to display data of both arrays in the same list then you have to use BaseAdapter and write your own logic for that.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: hello deepak ..when i combine two array items and make it one then also it display both array item  in same list...and as u said in second trick for,display data of both arrays in the same list ,also display data in same list then what will be the diffrence between two...pls pls explain...

Comment: means when using array adapter after combine it takes as an array and when usin Base adapter we can implement more then 1 0r2 items in same list view means can change no. of line in same list view ????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show more than one item in a list view item you can use your own Adapter by extending [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). But first of `array_ciudad` and `array_barrio` would need to be the same size.

Each Item will need to be represented by a list item layout like the one below. This layout would need to be placed in the `res/layout` directory.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Location where barrio items will be displayed -->                          
    <TextView android:id="@+id/barrio" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Location where ciudad items will be displayed -->                          
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ciudad"                 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />                      

</LinearLayout>
```

This example custom adapter assumes that both array_barrio and array_ciudad will be the same length. All you really need to do is create the view for the list items by inflating the layout and inserting your Strings into the TextViews where needed. In this example `MyAdapter` should be an inner class of `XMLParsingExample` giving it direct access to the array properties you defined.

```
protected class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super();
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }        

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return XMLParsingExample.this.array_barrio.length;
    }

    /* Not implemented but not really needed */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    /* Not implemented but not really needed */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { 
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_layout, parent, false);
        Course c = courses.get(position);

        String barrio = XMLParsingExample.this.array_barrio[position];
        String ciudad = XMLParsingExample.this.array_ciudad[position];            

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.barrio);
        tv.setText(barrio);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ciudad);
        tv.setText(ciudad);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: As @Deepak said if you want to combine two arrays then just use the method from @nicholas.hauschild.  But this should be helpful if you want to show two or more items/strings in one list item.

Comment: dear sir...first of all v v thanks for ur use full answer.. will be  any changes in XMLParsingExample.java class????so dont use array adapter inXMLParsingExample.java???

Comment: @atul-yadav  As long as your XML parsing is working fine the only change you will need is to add the `MyAdapter` class as an inner class in `XMLParsingExample`.  Then do not use `ArrayAdapter` instead use `new MyAdapter(this)`.  If you ware using `ListActivity` Then at the end of `onCreate` you will need `setListAdapter(adapter);`.